# backbone.js binding two function together to fire in sequence

Tags: backbone.js

Am trying to bind two functions in my backbone.js view but don't know why its not working..

any one can advise?

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'libs/jquery_ui_dependency',
    'vehicle/js/collections/MakeSet',
    'vehicle/js/collections/ModelSet',
    'vehicle/js/collections/TrimSet',
    'vehicle/js/collections/YearSet',
    'vehicle/js/views/Paginator'
], function($, _, Backbone, JQueryUi, MakeSet, ModelSet, TrimSet, YearSet, Paginator){
    'use strict';
    var BrowseVehicleView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#vehicle-browse-form'),
        initialize: function(){

            JQueryUi.init();

            _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'onMakeChange');

            //define array of elements to be used in DOM manipulations
            this.elements = {
                "make"       : $('#id_make',       this.el),
                "model"      : $('#id_model',      this.el),
                "trim"       : $('#id_trim',       this.el),
                "year_from"  : $('#id_year_from',  this.el),
                "year_to"    : $('#id_year_to',    this.el),
                "price_from" : $('#id_price_from', this.el),
                "price_to"   : $('#id_price_to',   this.el)
            }




        },
        events: {
            "change #id_make"           : "onMakeChange",
            "change #id_model"          : "onModelChange",
            "change #id_trim"           : "onTrimChange"
        },
        render: function(){

            Paginator.filter({
                model__make:   this.elements.make.val(),
                model__model:  this.elements.model.val(),
                model__trim:   this.elements.trim.val()
            });    

        },
        onMakeChange: function(event) {

            this.resetElement([
                this.elements.model,
                this.elements.trim,
                this.elements.year_from,
                this.elements.year_to
            ]);

            // load models
            this.RenderCollection(ModelSet, {make: this.elements.make.val()}, [this.elements.model]);


        },
```

what am trying to achieve here, is that every time onMakeChange is invoked it should invoke the render function as well to render the Paginator.filter()

Comment: What does `resetElement` do? What about `RenderCollection`? Generally you just bind `render` to an event (`"change"` or `"reset"` usually) and then do something to trigger that event. Either that or manually call `render`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_.bindAll ensures that when methods are called, the value of 'this' is set to the value you specify.  So, _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'onMakeChange') specifies that when render or onMakeChange is called, the BrowseVehicleView is set as the value of 'this'.

Like mu stated, you probably want to call this.render() manually inside of onMakeChange(), or bind this.render as an event handler to one of the events raised by your model.

Comment: thank you mate for explaining it. I was totally confused about the purpose of bindAll :)